# Truffle-upgrades - deployProxy - Type/values mismatch despite correct syntax

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, openzeppelin-contracts, proxy-contracts

Asking my first question here, hope it's in the right format.

I'm trying to deploy my contract using a transparent proxy, using OpenZeppelin's truffle-upgrades, as they explain [here](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/truffle-upgrades#migrations-usage).

However, I keep getting this error:

```
Error: types/values length mismatch (count={"types":1,"values":0}, value={"types":["uint256"],"values":[]}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.0.7)
```

This is strange because I'm sure I'm using the correct syntax. This is what my 2_deploy_blackjack.js migration looks like:

```
const { deployProxy } = require("@openzeppelin/truffle-upgrades");

const Blackjack = artifacts.require("Blackjack");


module.exports = async function (deployer) {   const instance = await deployProxy(Blackjack, [42], { deployer }); };
```

And this is what my contract's constructor looks like:

```
  constructor(uint256 _minBet) VRFConsumerBase(vrfCoordinator, link)
  {
    // Contract initializers
    admin = msg.sender;
    minBet = _minBet;

    // VRF initializers    
    s_keyHash = 0x2ed0feb3e7fd2022120aa84fab1945545a9f2ffc9076fd6156fa96eaff4c1311;
    s_fee = 100000000000000000;
    vrfCoordinator = 0xb3dCcb4Cf7a26f6cf6B120Cf5A73875B7BBc655B;
    link = 0x01BE23585060835E02B77ef475b0Cc51aA1e0709;
    linkToken = LinkTokenInterface(link);
  }
```

All solutions I've found online say I need to put my list of args in an array in my migration file, but I already do that. No idea why it still thinks I'm not giving any arguments. Thank you in advance - any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, but I got this error when trying to call `deployProxy` function.

I removed the constructor from the contract and leave `initialize` function only, then it works.